# AutoScroll to next/previous cell on swipe

Tags: ios, scrollview

I created a horizontal tableView, with cells that take up the whole view controller.   Instead of scrolling with the default setting, I would like to scroll to the next cell using `scrollView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath` method.

Meaning, each time the user scrolls right, it will automatically scroll to the next cell, and each time the user swipes left, it will automatically scroll to the previous cell.  Whenever you scroll a direction, it should automatically scroll to the next or previous cell. 

 I tried intercepting it using scrollViewDidScroll delegate method, but I am running into a ton of problems, it is autoscrolling back and forth and glitching a ton.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var previousOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
var allowHorizontalScroll: Bool = true

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (allowHorizontalScroll){
        let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        let diff = previousOffset - offset
        previousOffset = offset

        var currentBoardIndex = scrollView.indexPathForItem(at: CGPoint(x:offset, y:10))?.item
        if currentBoardIndex != nil {
            if diff > 0 {

                //print("scroll left")
                if (currentBoardIndex != 0){
                    currentBoardIndex = currentBoardIndex! - 1
                    allowHorizontalScroll = false
                    scrollView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: (currentBoardIndex!), section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
                }

            }else{

                //print("scroll right")
                if (currentBoardIndex != ((boardVCDataSource?.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count)! - 1)){
                    currentBoardIndex = currentBoardIndex! + 1
                    allowHorizontalScroll = false
                    scrollView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: (currentBoardIndex!), section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever you scroll a direction, it should automatically scroll to the next or previous cell.

Why not throw out all that code, and instead set your scroll view's `isPagingEnabled` to `true`? A paging scroll view does what you describe, *automatically*.